# How to remove or overwrite a `yasnippets`?

Tags: yasnippet

I am using Python but some pre-defineted snippets are acting not as I wanted, hence I want to remove some, if possible.

In most cases, I am using `TAB` for indent alignment, hence `yasnippets` apply themselve, which is pretty annoying.

For example:

In a Python file writing `log` and press `TAB`, `emacs` write followings code piece, which I want to disable:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("name")
        logger.setLevel(logging.level)
```

---

my setup:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'lsp)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lsp-deferred)

# taken from: https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet
(add-to-list 'load-path
              "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
```

---

```
Hide Yas Snippet Dirs: [Value Menu] List of directories:
[INS] [DEL] Choice: [Value Menu] Directory: ~/.emacs.d/snippets
[INS] [DEL] Choice: [Value Menu] Variable: yasnippet-snippets-dir
[INS] [DEL] Choice: [Value Menu] Variable: yasnippet-classic-snippets-dir
```

---

Please note that when I try to create a new snippet it generates it under `/home/user/etc/yasnippet/snippets/python-mode/` instead of `~/.emacs.d/snippets`.

Default snippets are located under `/usr/share/yasnippet-snippets/python-mode`; but since they require permission would it be a good idea to remove the ones that I don't want to use?

---

For example I want to remove following snippet keys for:

`__str__`, `str`, `size`, `def`, `self`, `__`

---

Basically,I just want to remove all `key` snippets for the given key. For example, when I type `str` and press `TAB` emacs says:

```
Possible completions are:
__str__                              str
. Choose a snippet:
```

where I don't want to see neither of it and completely remove all keys for the `str` key.

Comment: Snippets can be stored in a file.  The top section of the snippet contains items such `# key: ...`; ``# binding: ...``  See the tutorial:  https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html  If you don't like the key that triggers the snippet, then remove the entire line, or simply change the key to something you like better ...  I'm sure there is a way to reload the snippets on the fly after manually modifying them, but it is probably easier to just turn on/off the minor-mode, or restart Emacs.  Keep in mind that snippets can be inherited from another major-mode snippet folder.

Comment: I am trying to remove file that has `# key: str` but I couldn't where the main file for it to change @lawlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to remove a snippet from their place - at first update of yasnippet-snippet package, it will be again present in your Emacs.

So, a simpler method is to create new or modify/rename/save to the default `yas-snippet-dir`, which is `~/.emacs.d/snippets` folder (if you did not modify it already). But to be organised, add here a new folder `python-mode` where the new python snippets will be placed.

To modify an existing snippet and to place it in the default folder created, visit it and then use the command `save-as`, bound to `C-x C-w` instead the usual save command `C-x C-s`.  The “save-as” will allow you to choose destination folder.

The last thing to do is to take care to load all snippets (the original ones + yours) after python-mode is loaded - so add the line `(yas-reload-all)` after python mode is configured.

Comment: I have created `~/.emacs.d/snippets/python-mode`,(`(setq yas-snippet-dirs "~/.emacs.d/snippets/")`) added few snippet files in it and added `(yas-reload-all)` to the end of the `.emacs` file. But snippets are not fetched detected within the python-mode.

Comment: I had to do `C-h v yas-snippet-dir` `customize-variable` -> in order to re-set its path without having a problem

Comment: For example for `__str__`  and `str` I was not able to remove both of them and I not not sure where does  `__str__`  comes from.

Comment: The ```__str__``` comes from ```group dunder methods``` (google for "dunder methods") -  visit the snippet file with ```C-c & C-v```. Seems to be a name collision between ```str``` object from ```lsp``` and the key of ```__str__```. You may change the key for dunder method and save it in other place.

Comment: Its pretty difficult to code when there is random snippets apply themselves. I have look into all files under `~/.emacs.d/` I haven't able to find key for `__str__` any where. Please see my updated question for the directory paths.

Comment: I guess you are using Linux - and maybe installed within root - I do not use Linux; for me the path is ```~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-snippets/snippets/python-mode/str``` - similar is for ```len``` - and the other ```str``` is the python's str object. Maybe it will worth to report as a problem to yasnippet-snippet GitHub repository.

Comment: I have removed `~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-snippets/snippets/python-mode/str` but still `str` snippet keeps show up which drives me crazy

Comment: I do not have such behaviour; try also ```M-x yes-describe-tables```, maybe you can locate there the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easiest to remove the template in your init file after yasnippets is loaded. That way you don't have to modify the system directories. I think this should do it:

```
(yas--remove-template-by-uuid (yas--table-get-create 'python-mode) "logging")
```

Comment: This solution did not work on my end :-( Still snippets under `/usr/share/yasnippet-snippets/python-mode` takes place when I try to remve them for example adding: `(yas--remove-template-by-uuid (yas--table-get-create 'python-mode) "f")`

Comment: This doesn’t remove the actual snippet file, but after you run it I think that snippet should stop expanding which is what you want right?

Comment: Yes sir I was hoping to achieve that but it still exands after I added the `yas--remove-template-by-uuid`line

Comment: It might be the template name you need to use to remove it, and not the shortcut.